# Upload to google drive in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, google-drive-api

I would like to know , whether any solutions available for uploading file to google drive on user basis. Like I have an application, where users can upload their documents. I need to add an option for users to upload this document to their google drive also. So each user who have a gmail account can upload documents to their g drive. I've tried some solutions form google, but that allows  to upload documents to single user who crated this g drive app. You can see the code below. Please let me know if any user side oriented solution's are there.

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               new ClientSecrets
               {
                   ClientId = "clientid",
                   ClientSecret = "key",
               },
               new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
               "user",CancellationToken.None).Result;

        // Create the service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
        });

        File body = new File();
        body.Title = "My document";
        body.Description = "A test document";
        body.MimeType = "text/plain";

        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath( "document.txt"));
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
        request.Upload();

        File file = request.ResponseBody;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to integrate your code using OAuth2 authentication to authorize your app from the client and send the Authorization tokens to the server.
An Updated sample for MVC4 and Google Drive API Client Library 1.4+ can be found in the [Oauth 2.0 Documentation for .Net Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications)

Comment: are you, sure that it will help my application for gmail user authentication for users when an event is prompted?

Comment: From the bits of code provided what seems to be missing is forcing the user connecting with your app to authenticate on google servers and send the authorization token back to your server to save files on google drive on his/her behalf; and that code should do exactly that

Answer (score 1):

**" I've tried some solutions form google, but that allows to upload documents to single user who crated this g drive app"**

Are you sure? Most of the published Google sample apps use user OAuth to access the drive of the authorising user. It's only when looking at pages related to Service Accounts that the upload would be to an application account.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same problem. I resolved it by setting `_state=null` after uploading at first time. Yes, whenever we will click over the sharetodrive it will ask us regarding the permission again and again. But it's required to maintain the constraint (relevant user should have uploaded his files on Google Drive).